# How to return the controlling to default event handler?

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Given that I had installed my own mouse event handler,

but how can I return the controlling to default/system  event handler?

Because after installing my own mouse event handler,

and I pressed toolbar to add a sphere/box/cylinder to world

it turned out that the sphere/box/cylinder could not be released and placed on the ground

becuase "Mouse Release Event" is handled by my own mouse handler,default/system  event handler cannot listen to this event

How can I deal with this problem?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8500/how-to-return-the-controlling-to-default-event-handler?/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2015-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm assuming you added an event handler with `AddReleaseFilter`, like this for example:

```
MouseEventHandler::Instance()->AddReleaseFilter("my_plugin",
    boost::bind(&MyPlugin::OnMouseRelease, this, _1));
```

Your function returns a `bool` which indicates if the event was handled or not. So if you return false, the event will be propagated onwards. Return true to stop propagation.

```
bool MyPlugin::OnMouseRelease(const common::MouseEvent &_event)
{
  // Do what you want to do and decide if you want to propagate the event

  if (propagateEvent)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-04-17**:
thank you,but It did not work :( ;both OnMouseRelease and OnMousePress are return by false

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-04-17**:
and I have another question,why  I must use "glwidget" as the fisr parameter in AddPressFilter("glwidget"....)?
If I change to this  AddPressFilter("mysysgui"....), then my mouse handler can not be called

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-04-20**:
If you use "glwidget" as the first parameter, you're probably overriding the GLWidget's event handler, which is responsible for releasing shapes for example, so that's why this is not working for you. It should work with a custom string. Is your plugin a GUI Plugin?

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-04-21**:
Hi thank you,but if I change name other than "glwdiget", my mouse handler can not work.                   I am running gazebo 2.2 and use SystemPlugin,thank you~

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-04-23**:
I just confirmed this is an issue with System Plugins and created an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1575/it-isnt-possible-to-filter-mouse-events-in). I also checked that it works as expected with GUI plugins, so meanwhile you could work around this using a GUI plugin at least just for the events.

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-04-25**:
so, in  conclusion ,there is no available solution for SystemPlugin? And, gazebo 2.2 doesn't have GUIplugin, my only choice is updatint to gazebo 5.0 or higher?Thanks~

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-04-26**:
Yes, I think so.

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-04-28**:
ok Thank you~